# Android and making `this` a listener for one of its buttons

Tags: android, view, constructor, clicklistener

I have a custom view `MyView` inflated from `my_view.xml` (with a corresponding Java class `MyView.java`).

I override `MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` to connect subviews up to members of the class.

Now one of these subviews is a `Button`, and I'd like for my view to listen for a click on its button before passing this event on to a delegate. However if I declare

`this.myButton.setOnClickListener(this);`

in the constructor `MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` (where `this` is an instance of `MyView`) I get a `NullPointerException`.

Where is an appropriate place in `MyClass.java` to call `this.myButton.setOnClickListener(this);`?

%%

Edit. Some code:

```
public MyView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)
{
  super(context, attrs);
  this.myButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
  this.myButton.setOnClickListener(this); // Raises null pointer;'id' is correct.
}
```

Comment: Any place that doesn't get called until after `myButton` has been initialized, basically.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? This doesn't help much yet. For example, has `myButton` not been initialised once `super(ctx, attr)` been called? I'm calling `this.myButton.setOnClickListener(this);` after calling through to `super` of `MyView`.

Comment: I don't know the exact specifics of how Android loads a view, but I think it's reasonable to assume that it does not multithread the process.  If that is the case, then there is no way that `myButton` can be non-null until *after* your constructor returns, unless you manually set the button up yourself in your constructor.  The call to `super()` is largely irrelevant, since presumably the superclass does not know or care about `myButton`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to do the `setOnClickListener(this)` call in the constructor, do it after the button has been fully initialized.  Try moving `setOnClickListener(this)` so that it's called (indirectly) from the parent activity's `onResume` method like this:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new MyView(this, attrs).onResume();
    }
   ...
}

public class MyView {
    public void onResume() {
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
  ...
}
```

I use [Roboguice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) all the time for this sort of thing, and highly recommend it.  My button handler code looks like this:

```
class ButtonHandler implements OnClickListener {
    @InjectView(R.id.MainMenuButton)
    private Button button;

    public void onResumeEvent( @Observes OnResumeEvent onResume ) {
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doSomethingUseful();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Correct assumption. Showing some code now. Am I right in saying that the "button is fully initialised" only after `MyView`'s constructor has relinquished control?

Comment: @SK9, not necessarily.  See my edit for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I've missed off an inflate in the constructor:

```
LayoutInflater i = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
i.inflate(R.layout.my_view, this);
```

This is confusing for me as I'd thought the constructor `MyView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)` would be called in inflating the view, not the other way around.